# a python library I have written is found by the editor in vscode, but not when I run the calling file from the ide

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-module, pythonpath

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'data_dirs_module'
```

I'm using conda virtual environments and am quite comfortable with them. I have my project environment loaded into the python environment in vs-code.

I m not an expert at Python or vs-code.

The ide is happy to do `from data_dirs_module import dataDir, imageDir, loggingDir` and intellisense happily lets me add components from the library.

If I run a python interpreter in the same conda environment as loaded into the ide, i can import the library.

```
launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to run or debug the importing python file from vscode, it fails to find the library. I swapped to code-insiders. Same problem

Comment: please check mounted interpreter on your vscode. if it's pointing to same python version.

Comment: you can try adding the path to your library with 

`os.path.append("dir/to/your/library")`

before importing your library in any code

Comment: Thanks :-)
Run is behaving differently from edit in vscode. It is the same python version, and the same conda virtual environment. (i'm on ubuntu 18.04)
I have set PYTHONPATH at the command line I launched vs-code from. It seems that the editor and intellisense are using the environment of the command line, and that the run command is creating a new shell, ignoring the environment vs-code was launched from. the code runs fine when I launch it from the command line. 
How do I setup PYTHON path for the project within vscode?

Comment: Thanks Jorge - that seems like a work-around to me. I will use it for the moment. I don't think I should be embedding paths in my source .

Comment: There is supposed to be a .env  file that vscode reads in the project directory - seems to ignore it. Will investigate further.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file